# How to simplify multidimension array using Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, pscustomobject

I would like to create multidimension array in powershell, I tried this way and it works, but I want to simplified it to make it there is no repetition of `name` and `pn`. Anyone can give idea please, Thanks a lot

```
$array = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_1'; pn = 'gra-001'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_11a'; pn = 'ght-001'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_ca1'; pn = 'hasha-001'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_ga1'; pn = '45-001'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_4a1'; pn = 'aert-001'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'PRODCT_ata41'; pn = '43-001'}
  )
```

Comment: This is not an example of a multidimensional array.  It is a just a standard one-dimensional array made up of objects with multiple properties.

Comment: Why not use a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2)?

Answer (score 3):

Not really simplified but this is one way you could do it using an [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) and loop through the key / value pairs to create new instances of `PSCustomObject`:

```
$dict = [ordered]@{
    'PRODCT_1'     = 'gra-001'
    'PRODCT_11a'   = 'ght-001'
    'PRODCT_ca1'   = 'hasha-001'
    'PRODCT_ga1'   = '45-001'
    'PRODCT_4a1'   = 'aert-001'
    'PRODCT_ata41' = '43-001'
}
```

And then you can create the instances using either [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-ordereddictionary-getenumerator):

```
$dict.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.Key
        Pn   = $_.Value
    }
}
```

Or looping through the [*Keys*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.keys?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-ordereddictionary-keys):

```
$dict.PSBase.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_
        Pn   = $dict[$_]
    }
}
```

Lastly, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests you can combine `.GetEnumerator()` with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject):

```
$dict.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Name, @{N='Pn';E={$_.Value}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This creates an *actual* multidimensional array as the basis for generating the array of `[pscustomobject]`:

```sh
# Create multidimensional array
$temp = ('PRODCT_1', 'gra-001'),
        ('PRODCT_11a', 'ght-001'),
        ('PRODCT_ca1', 'hasha-001'),
        ('PRODCT_ga1', '45-001'),
        ('PRODCT_4a1', 'aert-001'),
        ('PRODCT_ata41', '43-001')

# Create single-dimensional array of pscustomobject
$array = $temp | Select-Object @{ n='name'; e={ $_[0] }}, 
                               @{ n='pn';   e={ $_[1] }}

# Output to console
$array
```

If you prefer, you could also do it using a single statement, without a temporary variable:

```sh
$array = (
    ('PRODCT_1', 'gra-001'),
    ('PRODCT_11a', 'ght-001'),
    ('PRODCT_ca1', 'hasha-001'),
    ('PRODCT_4a1', 'aert-001'),
    ('PRODCT_ata41', '43-001')
) | Select-Object @{ n='name'; e={ $_[0] }}, @{ n='pn'; e={ $_[1] }}
```

An even more succinct alternative using the intrinsic [`.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#foreach-and-where) method to directly create `[PSCustomObject]` array elements:

```sh
$array = (
    ('PRODCT_1', 'gra-001'),
    ('PRODCT_11a', 'ght-001'),
    ('PRODCT_ca1', 'hasha-001'),
    ('PRODCT_4a1', 'aert-001'),
    ('PRODCT_ata41', '43-001')
).ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{ name = $_[0]; pn = $_[1] } }
```

The latter is also the most efficient way, as it doesn't involve pipeline parameter-binding overhead.

Each of these produce the same **output:**

```text
name         pn
----         --
PRODCT_1     gra-001
PRODCT_11a   ght-001
PRODCT_ca1   hasha-001
PRODCT_ga1   45-001
PRODCT_4a1   aert-001
PRODCT_ata41 43-001
```

**Explanation for the `Select-Object` solutions:**

For each "row" of `$temp`, the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) command uses [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to turn the array elements into object properties.

E. g. it takes the row `('PRODCT_1', 'gra-001')`, which is an array of two elements. Then `@{ n='name'; e={ $_[0] }}` gets processed, which assigns the element at index 0 (`'PRODCT_1'`) to property `name`. Then `@{ n='pn'; e={ $_[1] }}` gets processed, which assigns the element at index 1 (`'gra-001'`) to property `pn`.

This process gets repeated for all remaining rows and we get an array of objects stored in `$array`, just like your original code does.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**

My answer keep the array of PSObject from your initial question but remove the name / pn repeat. I think in most cases, keeping the PSObject array structure is better (more flexible).

If you want an actual multidimensional array, [Zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42)'s answer is what you want.

---

You could use a function or scriptblock invoke. the values will be assigned positionally so you don't have to write the names (name, pn) each times.

**Using a function**

```
Function Add-product($Name, $pn) { [PSCustomObject]@{name = $Name; pn = $pn } }
  
  $array = @(
      Add-product 'PRODCT_1' 'gra-001'
      Add-product 'PRODCT_11a' 'ght-001'
      Add-product 'PRODCT_ca1' 'hasha-001'
  )
```

**Using a scriptblock invoke**

```
  $add = {Param($Name,$pn)  [PSCustomObject]@{name = $Name; pn = $pn}}
  $array = @(
      & $add 'PRODCT_1' 'gra-001'
      & $add 'PRODCT_11a' 'ght-001'
      & $add 'PRODCT_ca1' 'hasha-001'
  )
```

**Using CSV formatted data**

This one is just another way to do it, although I'd probably never use it in any scenario, since I prefer the flexibility of using a custom function / scriptblock. That being said, it is definitely the most compact.

```
$array = @'
Name,Pn
PRODCT_1,gra-001
PRODCT_11a,ght-001
PRODCT_ca1,hasha-001
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```